# How to merge two input records and Insert or Update accordingly in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Detail Question:  I have a function which takes inputs in the form of JSON and I would like to either Insert or Update the input into the existing table. Now, if I get multiple inputs, how do I handle.

**Table Structure**

```
create table sample ( colA Integer, colB character varying, colC character varying, colD character varying);

create type tt_sample AS 
(colA Integer, colB character varying, colC character varying, colD character varying);
```

**Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ins_upd_sample(
    tt_sample text)
    RETURNS timestamp without time zone
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    
AS $BODY$
DECLARE

BEGIN
   with cte as(
        INSERT INTO sample(
                    colA, colB, colC, colD
                )   
                SELECT 
                    tmd.colA, tmd.colB, tmd.colC, tmd.colD
                FROM json_populate_recordset(null::tt_sample ,tt_sample::json) tmd
                
                LEFT JOIN sample md ON 
                    md.colA = tmd.colA 
                    AND md.colB = tmd.colB  
                WHERE   md.colB IS NULL
                RETURNING * /*Some Usage*/
                )

                /*some usage*/
            with cte2 as(
          UPDATE sample md SET
                    colC = tmd.colC, colD = tmd.colD
                
                FROM json_populate_recordset(null::tt_sample ,tt_sample::json) tmd
                 where md.colA = tmd.colA AND md.colB = tmd.colB     
                    AND md.colB IS NOT NULL
                RETURNING */*some usage */   
                )
                    /*some usage*/
                    
          return(   SELECT
        /*timestamp */);
    END;
   
 
$BODY$;
```

**INPUTS:**

```
select ins_upd_sample ('[{"colA":21, "colB":"abc", "colC":null, "colD":null},
{"colA":21, "colB":"abc", "colC":"xyz, "colD":"xyz"}]')
```

**Desired Result :**
Only 1 record should be in the table. First record should get Inserted and next record should get updated. I am getting two Inserted record, and is duplicate. ( obviously, update is there for second one ).

Is it possible to commit the transatcion in between.

Comment: to update rows you need to use where condition then you can update rows you wanted

Comment: ahh No i guess. Here, its different, the data is in the inputs, against which I have to checked whether to Insert or Update. Please suggests your way.

Comment: you mean that there cant be 2 rows in one table, am i right?

Comment: correct.  My approach will only check with respect to database. But, since these two records, both are in same input, I am not able to UPSSERT ( in a sense ). What is happening is - first one is getting Inserted, second once is also getting Inserted, ( second one cant check, the first one is already in the table )

Comment: so you need check database is there any data or rows if exist update it else insert new row that is it

Comment: ok. I think you are not getting exactly.

Comment: so what you want, share sample data and expected data from query is it possible

Comment: Input is there in the details : 
select ins_upd_sample ('[{"colA":21, "colB":"abc", "colC":null, "colD":null},
{"colA":21, "colB":"abc", "colC":"xyz, "colD":"xyz"}]')

Comment: As you can see, there are two input records for the same table.  Desired result would be, first one should get Inserted and the next one should get updated. So, total only 1 record present in the table.

Comment: finally i got it

Comment: Hmm, might be a case where procedural logic is needed, i.e. loop over all the elements of the JSON array and handle each one individually.

Comment: yes, looping is one option, but the actual data is so big, if I use loop and process one by one, its a problem, thats why want to check, if there is any tricks or any other options..

Comment: Why are you not sending it in one input I think it is not possible that what you want maybe you should send input as one input not extracting it, from front side you

Comment: Thats the thing, if I can Merge the two inputs into one.  Merging in application level might be possible,  but I also want to merge in DB level, as a failsafe.

Comment: I will try with a TEMP Table, doing the upsert in temp table..then gradually move it to the main table. let's see, if you guys have any other good ideas, let me know please. No harm in experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a possible workaround. Add a column that only allows 1 value ie a default and a check constraint that value is the default and it is unique. Now in your insert do not reference this column, just take the default. So something like:

```
create table <your_table> 
       ( ...  
       , singleton  varchar(1) default 'A'
       , constraint singleton_bk unique (singleton)
       , constraint singleton check (singleton = 'A')
       ) ;
```

Then revise insert to:

```
insert into <your_table>( ... )       -- omit column singleton
     values (...)
     on conflict (singleton)
     do update 
           set <column> = excluded.<columns>;
```

See example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=23f793b62d7c1f4b41f9a25a7c55be4f).